# JprogressBar functioning with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a multithreading project that simulates queues. I wish to show how clients arrive at queue(each queue is another thread) and how they pass through it with a progress bar.  I wish to have multiple JProgressBars in different frames, each to show how a specific queue works(the queue number is input from the main interface).I have searched online for tutorials but I couldn't find something to help me. Could someone explain or link me how it works. Or if somebody has a better idea(another swing component or idea) that could help me simulate a queue in real time, I would be grateful. I am open to any kind of advice. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your worker threads call:

```
final int val = <desiredValue>;
EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{progressBarN.setProgress(val);});
```

This will ensure no AWT errors and will work fine in multithreaded environment.

Added:
But if you do increments/decrements, do them inside invokeLater call, otherwise you can get wrong values due to threading.

```
final int val = <desiredIncrement>;
EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{progressBarN.setProgress(progressBarN.getProgress()+val);});
```

Comment: But if i decrease the value(because at one point I will run out of clients and the queues are empty) wouldn't that cause an error? (Increasing then decreasing the bar)

Comment: Sure, you can move it in any direction. Be sure to set the min and max for it to scale properly.

Comment: It didn't. In the end I used something else to show the queues progression. Regardless of what I did, I couldn't show the evolution by JProgressBar.

Comment: @Maria then you can post your solution for others to use. You can answer your own question.